# Why isn't Lua reevaluating io.read("*n")?

Tags: validation, input, lua

I have some code

```
::redo::
io.write("input: ")
var = io.read("*n")
if var then
    if var > 5 and var < 10 then io.write("yes\n") goto redo
    else io.write("invalid\n") goto redo end
else io.write("invalid\n") goto redo end
```

that is supposed to check a numeric input value and return if it's within a certain range.  If it isn't a numeric value, it's supposed to "redo" the script and ask for input again.  The issue is that whenever it takes an input that isn't a number it repeats `io.write("input: ")` and `io.write("invalid\n")` unceasingly meaning it's skipping the `var = io.read("*n")` line.  Is there a special meaning or quirk to `io.read("*n")` that keeps it from reevaluating?  The code seems to work if replaced with `io.read()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call `io.read('*n')` and it doesn't find a number, it doesn't use up the input, and any calls to `io.read('*n')` will read the same input over and over. You need to eat up the input and discard it by calling `io.read('*l')`. That will let you read new input with `io.read('*n')`.

Another method would be to read a line with  `io.read('*l')`, extract a number from it with `string.match` and convert it to a number with `tonumber`. Then you don't have to read the same input twice, but you'd have to decide what types of number notation you want to match. ([`io.read('*n')`](https://www.lua.org/source/5.3/liolib.c.html#read_number) accepts various types of numbers, including hexadecimal and scientific notation.)